# JQuery hover with time

Tags: jquery, css

I do have a problem with a jquery. I have a divblock with "show_your_stuff". When I do a mouse over another div-block appears, what I want. When I do a mouse over again, the divblock is getting away. I want that the divblock disappears after 60 seconds, when without doing a new mouse over again. Can somebody help me?

This is my code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("a#controlbtn").hover(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var slidepx=$("div#linkblock").width() + 10;
            if ( !$("div#maincontent").is(':animated') ) { 
                if (parseInt($("div#maincontent").css('marginRight'), 10) < slidepx) {

                  $(this).addClass('close').html('Show your stuffs');
                    margin = "+=" + slidepx;

                     } else {
                    $(this).removeClass('close').html('Hide your stuffs');
                     margin = "-=" + slidepx;
                }
                $("div#maincontent").animate({ 
                    marginRight: margin
                }, {
                    duration: 'slow',
                    easing: 'easeOutQuint'
                });
            } 
        }); 

    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `setTimeout` and `clearTimeout` to postpone and cancel the hide effect when the mouse leaves and reenters respectively:

```
$(element).mouseover(function() {
    if (typeof delayTime != 'undefined')
        window.clearTimeout(delayTime);
    $('#tooltip').animate({/*CSS to show element*/},{duration: XXX, queue: false});
});
$(element).mouseout(function() {
    delayTime = window.setTimeout(function(){
        $('#tooltip').animate({/*CSS to hide element*/},{duration: XXX, queue: false});
    }, XXX);
});
```

...Where each `XXX` is a number representing delay or durration in milliseconds.

Comment: Thanks! #tooltip is this my div-name? I am sorry, but it is not working.

Comment: `#tooltip` is a dummy `id` value for the element you're trying to show/hide on mouseover/mouseout. You'll need to replace this with the `class` or `id` or whatever selector that effectively returns the element you're actually targeting in your code.

Comment: Can you might post the html-code for me or/and CSS? But I guess the html code would be better. I really don't know what I am doing wrong!

Comment: Here is a working example of the behavior it sounds like you're trying to achieve, plus a handler for when the mouse leaves one of the original 'base' divs to enter its corresponding 'tooltip' div.
http://jsfiddle.net/5M9as/

Comment: Thanks man! That is what I exactly want! Oh, JQuery aren't so nice! You can do a lot of things with it, but it is not so logic in my opinion sometimes. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will help you but its worth a check out..

http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html

Answer (score 0):

Arron posted a link! That is working:

http://jsfiddle.net/5M9as/

Craphunter

Answer (score 0):

I use HoverIntent as well for tasks like this.  It has features such as sensitivity and timeout.  Sensitivity meaning that you can move X number of pixels away from your hover item before it fires the "out" event and timeout for the amount of time outside of the hoveritem before firing the out event.